# Game Server Blocking Tor Somehow

Tags: proxy, ip, tor

So, I've been connecting to one of my games through a proxy connection (tor). Recently, the connection attempt to the game servers simply times out. This was right after an "update" to the game. My guess is that because of problems that moderators have been having with trolls, they removed the ability to connect via tor. Is there any way around this?

Comment: is this a programming related question ???

Comment: Move to superuser, you think?

Answer (score 0):

The simple alternative would be to not use tor. Why is it that you need to connect through a proxy?

You can find a cheap shared hosting plan for ~$10-50 per year. Some of them have unlimited bandwidth and allow SSH tunneling, etc.

IMO it's a much better, and reliable alternative to Tor (so long as you're not doing anything illegal =P)

Answer (score 0):

You can't "IP Ban TOR", because TOR comes out of a very large number of possible IPs. However, there are other possible issues. TOR can cause very high ping, so if the maximum ping was lowered that could cause the problem. Additionally, your account may have been blocked from the server, or the TOR users don't have particular ports open. If you want a good answer, try explaining why you need TOR for gaming so we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Where was Minecraft mentioned? Also, Tor only connects out through specially configured relays (specifically, exit relays). The typical connection to Tor is not as a relay.

Comment: Got two posts confused. guess this one was general. OK, all users is inaccurate, but there are still a lot of relays, are there not? Would it really be plausible to ban all of them, all at once?

Comment: You can "IP ban Tor" because the list of Tor exit relays is freely available. See for example: http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

Answer (score 0):

The detection of Tor on the server side usually works by comparing the source IP address to the list of IP addresses of the Tor exit relays which is freely available. See for example http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

If you really need to use Tor the solution could be to change the source IP address once more after exiting the Tor network. There are two basic means:

- **Proxy over Tor**

  - Through the Tor network connect to a proxy server. The proxy server must handle the protocols used by the application/game.
- **VPN over Tor**

  - Connect the VPN client to the VPN gateway through the Tor network. The VPN must run over TCP (for example SSL VPN) because Tor transports only TCP.

For both solutions:

1. The exit IP addresses of the VPN gateway or proxy must not be blocked by the application/game.
2. You must be able to route the traffic to the proxy or the VPN gateway through the Tor network. For example [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) could take care of it.
3. To keep your anonymity any identification you use with the proxy or VPN services must not be re-used or connected to activities without being protected by Tor. Not adhering to this principle could make the anonymization by Tor relaying pointless.